# Link to Other Page that open another tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 html page .. the first page is Header.html with 2 links (addressbook, mybook). My 2nd page is the Main-body.html has tabs with Addressbook and mybook. Since they are both different page, how can I manage to open the tabs using the links on the first page ..

**example** : header.html > (link)addressbook > main-body.html >(open tab addressbook)

header.html > (link)myorder > main-body.html > (open tab mybook)
using jquery ..

Comment: what have you done already ?? and paste your code ??

Comment: Actually, what is the question?

Comment: sorry .. let me elaborate my question .. I want to open my second page displaying second tabs using the 2nd link on my first page ..

I haven't done any JS for the question yet .. still doing it

Comment: Okay, I guess, but be clear: with tabs, do you mean your own tabs on the page or tabs from the browser? Because that last one will not give you any control, the first one is doable. Try to be as clear as possible when asking a question, as unambiguous as you can and provide as much detail as necessary to replicate the problem or issue you are attempting to solve. It is also greatly appreciated if you give it a go yourself before asking us.

Answer (score 2):

You can use hashchange event, and use hash to navigate directly to your content tab, like this:

```js
$(function() {
    // First hide all content element
    $("#xxx,#yyy").hide();
 
    $(window).on("hashchange", function(e){    
  // Hide all content elements
        $("#xxx,#yyy").hide();
        
        // Show only the desired element
        $(location.hash).show(); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#xxx">xxx</a>
<a href="#yyy">yyy</a>

<p id="xxx">
    xxx
</p>
<p id="yyy">
    yyy
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you would like to have a tabbed design on `main-body.html`. In this case I would use anchors:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="main-body.html#addressbook">Address Book</a></li>
    <li><a href="main-body.html#mybook">My Order</a></li>
<ul>
```

Then, you need to handle the achor with JavaScript. Depending on the value, you can show a different tab.

Comment: thx for the response guys .. even if I didnt post my html structure .. actually I'm still trying to post my html here but I dont know where I put it .. 
ill try your response using your html .. thanks ..

Comment: Your right about what I want to do .. having the main-body with tabs widget and want to control it with the link on the other page .. thanks :)